# WPF pie chart - slices not displayed on the chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, pie-chart, codeplex

I'm trying to use a WPF pie chart.  The problem is that only the last slice remains displayed.  I can see that all slices are displayed and immediatly hidden except the last one.  Any idea ?

```
<Window x:Class="ScrumApp01.WindowGraphique"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" 
    xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrumApp01"
    Title="Fenêtre graphiques SCRUM" Height="674" Width="1216" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Name="GraphicScrum01">

<DVC:Chart Margin="25,268,0,0" Title="Pointe de tarte" LegendTitle="Les datas" Background="LightSteelBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="324" Width="307">
<DVC:PieSeries Title="Les datas en tarte" Name="Tarte2"
    ItemsSource="{StaticResource FruitCollection2}"
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=sss}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=nnn}" >
</DVC:PieSeries>
```

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FruitCollection2 fff = new FruitCollection2();
  fff.Clear();
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[0], bbb = 1, ddd = 10, sss =   "Item a" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[1], bbb = 2, ddd = 9, sss = "Item b" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[2], bbb = 3, ddd = 11, sss = "Item c" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[3], bbb = 1, ddd = 14, sss = "Item d" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[4], bbb = 4, ddd = 7, sss = "Item e" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[5], bbb = 5, ddd = 1, sss = "Item f" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[6], bbb = 6, ddd = 7, sss = "Item g" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[7], bbb = 3, ddd = 6, sss = "Item h" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[8], bbb = 3, ddd = 7, sss = "Item i" });
  fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[9], bbb = 4, ddd = 5, sss = "Item j" });


  this.Tarte2.ItemsSource = fff;

}
```

Comment: What is the `DVC` namespace? Which pie chart are you using?

Comment: I edited the code and added the headers

Comment: Are "nnn", "sss" properties or fields? Binding won't work if its fields.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting the ItemsSource on your Chart is strange. Doing it this way should work:

At the Class `sss` defined as referred by `{Binding Path=sss}`(Basically the DataContext of DVC:PieSeries), declare this property:

```
private ObservableCollection<Fruit02> mFff = new ObservableCollection<Fruit02>();
public ObservableCollection<Fruit02> fff
{
    get { return mFff; }
}
```

Then Bind your DVC:PieSeries ItemSource like so:

```
<DVC:PieSeries Title="Les datas en tarte" Name="Tarte2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fff}"
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=sss}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=nnn}" >
</DVC:PieSeries>
```

Then in your click handler, don't create a new Collection, just modify the existing one:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fff.Clear();
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[0], bbb = 1, ddd = 10, sss = "Item a" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[1], bbb = 2, ddd = 9, sss = "Item b" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[2], bbb = 3, ddd = 11, sss = "Item c" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[3], bbb = 1, ddd = 14, sss = "Item d" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[4], bbb = 4, ddd = 7, sss = "Item e" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[5], bbb = 5, ddd = 1, sss = "Item f" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[6], bbb = 6, ddd = 7, sss = "Item g" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[7], bbb = 3, ddd = 6, sss = "Item h" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[8], bbb = 3, ddd = 7, sss = "Item i" });
        fff.Add(new Fruit02 { nnn = this.data001.listeNombres03[9], bbb = 4, ddd = 5, sss = "Item j" });
    }
```

Assuming your DataContext is set up correctly and your Pie Chart Control is implemented properly, this should work.

Comment: Well .. same result ... I think I will give up ! :)